# Retrieve Data in mvc View

Tags: javascript, json, model-view-controller

I currently have this script in MVC view

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(".bar_dashboard").peity("bar", {
            fill: ["#1ab394", "#d7d7d7"],
            width: 100
        })

        $("#sparkline8").sparkline([5, 6, 7, 2, 0, 4, 2, 4, 5, 7, 2, 4, 12, 14, 4, 2, 14, 12, 7], {
            type: 'bar',
            barWidth: 8,
            height: '150px',
            barColor: '#1ab394',
            negBarColor: '#c6c6c6'
        });

        var updatingChart = $(".updating-chart").peity("line", { fill: '#1ab394', stroke: '#169c81', width: 64 })

        setInterval(function () {
            var random = Math.round(Math.random() * 10)
            var values = updatingChart.text().split(",")
            values.shift()
            values.push(random)

            updatingChart
                .text(values.join(","))
                .change()
        }, 1000);

        var data1 = [
            [0, 4], [1, 8], [2, 5], [3, 10], [4, 4], [5, 16], [6, 5], [7, 11], [8, 6], [9, 11], [10, 30], [11, 10], [12, 13], [13, 4], [14, 3], [15, 3], [16, 6]
        ];
        var data2 = [
            [0, 1], [1, 0], [2, 2], [3, 0], [4, 1], [5, 3], [6, 1], [7, 5], [8, 2], [9, 3], [10, 2], [11, 1], [12, 0], [13, 2], [14, 8], [15, 0], [16, 0]
        ];
        $("#flot-dashboard-chart").length && $.plot($("#flot-dashboard-chart"), [
            data1, data2
        ],
                {
                    series: {
                        lines: {
                            show: false,
                            fill: true
                        },
                        splines: {
                            show: true,
                            tension: 0.4,
                            lineWidth: 1,
                            fill: 0.4
                        },
                        points: {
                            radius: 0,
                            show: true
                        },
                        shadowSize: 2
                    },
                    grid: {
                        hoverable: true,
                        clickable: true,
                        tickColor: "#d5d5d5",
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        color: '#d5d5d5'
                    },
                    colors: ["#1ab394", "#464f88"],
                    xaxis: {
                    },
                    yaxis: {
                        ticks: 4
                    },
                    tooltip: false
                }
        );

        var doughnutData = [
            {
                value: 300,
                color: "#a3e1d4",
                highlight: "#1ab394",
                label: "App"
            },
            {
                value: 50,
                color: "#dedede",
                highlight: "#1ab394",
                label: "Software"
            },
            {
                value: 100,
                color: "#b5b8cf",
                highlight: "#1ab394",
                label: "Laptop"
            }
        ];

        var doughnutOptions = {
            segmentShowStroke: true,
            segmentStrokeColor: "#fff",
            segmentStrokeWidth: 2,
            percentageInnerCutout: 45, // This is 0 for Pie charts
            animationSteps: 100,
            animationEasing: "easeOutBounce",
            animateRotate: true,
            animateScale: false,
        };

        var ctx = document.getElementById("doughnutChart").getContext("2d");
        var DoughnutChart = new Chart(ctx).Doughnut(doughnutData, doughnutOptions);

        var polarData = [
            {
                value: 300,
                color: "#a3e1d4",
                highlight: "#1ab394",
                label: "App"
            },
            {
                value: 140,
                color: "#dedede",
                highlight: "#1ab394",
                label: "Software"
            },
            {
                value: 200,
                color: "#b5b8cf",
                highlight: "#1ab394",
                label: "Laptop"
            }
        ];

        var polarOptions = {
            scaleShowLabelBackdrop: true,
            scaleBackdropColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0.75)",
            scaleBeginAtZero: true,
            scaleBackdropPaddingY: 1,
            scaleBackdropPaddingX: 1,
            scaleShowLine: true,
            segmentShowStroke: true,
            segmentStrokeColor: "#fff",
            segmentStrokeWidth: 2,
            animationSteps: 100,
            animationEasing: "easeOutBounce",
            animateRotate: true,
            animateScale: false,
        };
        var ctx = document.getElementById("polarChart").getContext("2d");
        var Polarchart = new Chart(ctx).PolarArea(polarData, polarOptions);

    });
</script>
```

I want to change

```
var data1 = [
            [0, 4], [1, 8], [2, 5], [3, 10], [4, 4], [5, 16], [6, 5], [7, 11], [8, 6], [9, 11], [10, 30], [11, 10], [12, 13], [13, 4], [14, 3], [15, 3], [16, 6]
        ];
var data2 = [
            [0, 1], [1, 0], [2, 2], [3, 0], [4, 1], [5, 3], [6, 1], [7, 5], [8, 2], [9, 3], [10, 2], [11, 1], [12, 0], [13, 2], [14, 8], [15, 0], [16, 0]
        ];
```

to read dynamic data from my Controller using JSON how can I do that?

Comment: you need to make an a call to the controller from JS, so through an xhr request / ajax is 1 example ? Unless i've missed something ? Can you show us your controller ? Or tell us how its exposed to the outside ?

Comment: I have some problem understanding your question. Do you wanna make a n AJAX call to read data? JSON is a way to represent data, like xml, you can't use JSON to "read" data. Please give us some information even about the MVC framework you're using.

Comment: there is no code in my control I need for an example to change the static values in the code above with a values from my controller using json code or some thing else

Comment: what server side do you have ? What is providing the dynamic JSON ? For example, php ? c# ? nodeJS ?

Answer (score 0):

You need a method in your controller which provides you the information you want.

```
public String getData(){
   int[,] ints = new int[,] { {1,1},{2,2},{3,3} };
   var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ints);
}
```

In your view you can get it like this:

```
$.get("/Controller/getData", null, function (data) {
        thisismydata = data;
    });
```

---

If you want to do this async take a look at `$.ajax()`. You can find more information [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).